# How to extract all cookies in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

is there a way to extract all cookies from selenium using python?
I mean all cookies which browser has collected not only those from current site

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you meant by extract all cookies, but in case if you want to grab all the cookies, you can do something like this  :

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cokie in cookies:
    print(cokie)
```

This line  :

```
driver.get_cookies()
```

will return a list of cookies.

Comment: for example i visiting 'http://google.com/' and now i have 4 cookies, but if i go to 'http://example.com/' i dont have access to those 4 cookies from google anymore.
so is there any way to get all cookies which browser collected?

Comment: yes that's what the above code does. did you try it out  ?

Comment: no, this code show cookies from current site  same like "document.cookie;"
i want to obtain every one cookie which my browser saved